# Error: the elements, tuples, and sets in the function must use the same hierarchies

Tags: mdx, hierarchy, olap, olap-cube, cross-join

Please help! I'm trying to write a query that will return a table with dates in the rows and order details in the columns, but I received error:

Query (3, 3) The elements, tuples, and sets in the function must use the same hierarchies.

```
 SELECT
     [Calendar].[YMD].[Day] on rows,
     {[Measures].[Orders Approved EUR],
     [Measures].[Orders Approved PCS],
     [Measures].[Orders Approved count],
     [Measures].[Orders Gross EUR],
     [Measures].[Orders Gross PCS],
     [Measures].[Orders Gross count],
     [Measures].[Orders Net EUR],
     [Measures].[Orders Net PCS],
     [Measures].[Orders Net count],
     [Online_store].[Order_code].[Order_code], 
     [Online_store].[Payment_type].[Payment_type],
     [Online_store].[Client_Vip].[Client_Vip],
     [Order_line_online_store].[Source].[Source],
     [Order_line_online_store].[Reason for line cancellation].[Reason for line cancellation],
     [Goods].[ItemID].[ItemID],
     [Goods].[КТТ].[Level 01],
     [Goods].[КТТ].[Level 02],
     [Goods].[КТТ].[Level 03],
     [Goods].[КТТ].[Level 04],
     [Goods].[КТТ].[Level 05],
     [Goods].[КТТ].[Level 06],
     [Goods].[КТТ].[Level 07]}
     on columns
 FROM [eShop]
 WHERE 
{[Calendar].[Season_calendar].[Day].[01.01.2021 (Friday)]:
 strtomember("[Calendar].[Season_calendar].[Day].[" + Format(now()-1, "dd.MM.yyyy (dddd)") + "]")}
```